# NFC Emulate card witout root

Tags: java, android, emulation, nfc, card

I am developing a simple app that emulates reading a card.

The big problem is, is it possible to emulate a card WITHOUT root access on an Android device?

if yes, can you share your information

thank you all.

I have looked at the following:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce

this is the working app with root access only
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yuanwofei.cardemulator.pro&hl=tr&gl=US

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different types of NFC Tags

You can emulate a Type 4 tag without rooting the phone.
As you have seen this can be done as per https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce

An example of HCE is available at https://github.com/underwindfall/NFCAndroid

This works without rooting the phone.

I believe that some (not all) phone hardware might be able to emulate one other type of Tag if you have rooted the phone and know the non public API to access the hardware in the right manner (not confirmed).

Comment: is possıable to emulate Tag Type ISO 14443-3A   NXP MİFARE CLASSİC 1K with out root for example

Comment: Tag 4 Type:   The NFC Tag 4 Type is defined to be compatible with ISO 14443A and ISO 14443B standard (13.56MHz).  This mean we can emulate this with HCE right

Comment: "Emulate MİFARE CLASSİC 1K with out root", this is the one that I believe that if your phone uses a NXP chipset it might be possible with a rooted phone, but not all phones use NXP chipsets. Just to clarify I believe that only the "A" modulation is supported by HCE and you have no control over the ISO 14443 level of the protocol (ISO 14443 is just used for anti collision and the UID related to that is a random number). HCE only gives you control of the ISO 7816-4 (Application protocol) used by type 4 Tags

Comment: https://shop.sonmicro.com/SM5210 is this rfid chip can read phone emulator nfc. or how to know its type is ?